# How to set universal path in method's attribute

Tags: c#, data-driven-tests

I wrote a test. I use Data Driven Unit Tests. My method declaration looks like follow:

```
[TestCategory("IntegrationTest")]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV",
"C:\\MyProjectPath\\File.csv", "File#csv",
DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("File.csv"),
TestMethod]
public void Read_CSV_File_Attribute()
```

I want to commit my changes to source control. The problem which I have is hardcoded path in DataSource attribute: "C:\MyProjectPath\File.csv".

If somebody will get latest version of this code from repository then this person will have to change a path in this attribute.

How to make universal path that will work for all my c-workers?

---

I've tried to change path by using:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("Read_CSV_File_Attribute");
method.CustomAttributes.ElementAt(1).ConstructorArguments.ElementAt(1).Value = _newPath;
```

It doesn't work because Value is read-only.

---

```
[TestCategory("IntegrationTest")]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV",
Path.Combine(), "File#csv",
DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("File.csv"),
TestMethod]
public void Read_CSV_File_Attribute()
```

Combine() throws a message: Cannot resolve symbole 'Combine'.

---

I also tried to use ConfigurationManager class, but I get an information: Class name is not valid at this point.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include File.csv to your project and copy it to the output directory (right click on File.csv in solution => Properties => Advanced => Copy to Output Directory => Copy if newer)
2. Use a relative path to "File.csv" in `DataSourceAttribute`:

   ```
   [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", 
           "File.csv", "File#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
   ```

Comment: I followed your steps and my test failed with message: The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests" [...]. Error details: The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'File.csv'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
When I write [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "D:\\File.csv", "File#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)] then test works.

Comment: @Jaryn Was the File.csv file copied in the bin/debug folder of the test project? Did you put the file to "D:\\" manually? Is it possible to check System.Environment.CurrentDirectory and System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory values?

Answer (score 0):

The problem which I hit occured because of a folder structure. I had in my solution explorer a structure like folllow:

```
TestProject
  -> Folder1
    -> Folder2
      -> File.csv
      -> Tests.cs
```

I ran tests. In bin/debug folder I didn't see File.csv. File.csv was inside folder structre:

```
bin
  -> debug 
    -> Folder1
      -> Folder2
        -> File.csv
```

The solution for my problem was to change a path to file:

```
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", 
        @"Folder1\Folder2\File.csv", "File#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```